# UICollectionView can't show all content

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I init the collectionview with this(with code not the storyboard):

```
-(id) init{
    self = [super init];
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    self.page = 0;
    self.step = 20;
    self.subCateItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.scaleFactor = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width / 375.f;
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(9.f*self.scaleFactor, 6.f*self.scaleFactor, 0, 6.f*self.scaleFactor);
    _collectionView=[[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame collectionViewLayout:layout];
    _collectionView.mj_header = [MJRefreshNormalHeader headerWithRefreshingBlock:^{
        self.page = 0;
        [self updateData];
    }];

    [_collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [_collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [_collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier"];
    [_collectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:_collectionView];

    return self;
}
```

but the collection view seems can't show all the collection cells:

[image]

How to fix this?

as comments have suggested, I have caputured the view hierarchy of the views

[image]

Comment: Seems more to be an issue with Constraints or CollectionView Offset. Could you check with Hierarchy Debug in XCode https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html that the frames seem correct?

Comment: Hi, @Larme I added this collectionview with code not the storyboard, how can I fix that with code?

Comment: checkout the constraint you have given to collectionview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your scroll view indicators, the bottom inset of the scroll view is set incorrectly, as it underlaps `UITabBar`. The code is in Swift but you should get the idea ;-)

I usually do this to make my scroll views appear on top:

```
_collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -50, 0) 
_collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, -50, 0)
```

Also, make sure to make this:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: Hi, since I only use the collectionView as a @property and implement the protocol of the `UICollectionView` ,  so couldn't find a place to modify the  `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, but make the Inserts works

Comment: Great! `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` is actually a property on `UIViewController`, it may be handy in many ways, not just in this scenario

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is here

```
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Must be like this

```
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

Then, who is the `self` ? Is it tab of `UITabBarController`?
If yes, all is good. If no then you will set correct inset of`UICollectionView`